# How to parse regex ,received as a api responce

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

My use case is I get Regex from a api response, which I have to use for validation purpose.

I get such a response

```
{  
   valid:'/^4/',
   displayName:'Card'
}
```

Now i convert the regex string to valid Regex

```
var rec = new RegExp(res.valid); //  /\/^4\//
```

Which is not desired.
How can i convert regex in stringified form to Valid regex (/^4/).

Comment: `new RegExp` does not require `/` delimiters.

Answer (score 2):

When defining a regex in a *string*, we don't use `/` around it. Those are the *literal* form. By passing a string with `/` on it into `new RegExp`, you're making it think the `/` are part of the expression.

Just remove them:

```
var rec = new RegExp(res.valid.substring(1, res.valid.length - 1));
```

Actually, thinking about it, you may need to go further than that, if there are flags on the regex (like `valid: '/^x/i'`):

```
var rec;
var valid = res.valid;
var match;
if (valid[0] === "/") {
    match = valid.match(/\/([gimuy]*)$/);
}
if (match) {
    rec = new RegExp(valid.substring(1, valid.length - match[0].length), match[1] || "");
} else {
    rec = new RegExp(valid);
}
```

```js
var res = {
  valid: "/^x/i"
};

var rec;
var valid = res.valid;
var match;
if (valid[0] === "/") {
    match = valid.match(/\/([gimuy]*)$/);
}
if (match) {
    rec = new RegExp(valid.substring(1, valid.length - match[0].length), match[1] || "");
} else {
    rec = new RegExp(valid);
}
console.log(rec.test("xyz")); // true
console.log(rec.test("Xyz")); // true
console.log(rec.test("zyx")); // false
```